# How can I sort the children in a gx:Track?

Tags: python, kml, google-earth, pykml

I'm using pyKML to generate a KML file containing several gx:Tracks with several `<when>`, `<gx:coord>`, and `<gx:angles>` tags. It seems that the schema wants these tags in order, meaning first all `<when>` tags, then the `<gx:coord>` tags, and so on.

For my file generation it is more convenient however to write the tags intermixed, meaning `<when1><coord1><angles1><when2><coord2>...` inside the `<gx:Track>` tag.

Is there some way to sort the tags again after adding using lxml/pyKML, or do I have to search for the last `<when>` tag and insert the new tags manually at the correct positions?